# How to import the latest published excel file in R?

Tags: r, excel, file, import, readxl

I have a folder with several excel files. I can read the file with the readxl function. However, I would like to know if there is any option to read the last published file in the folder. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try with `file.info`

Comment: I would be very careful about doing this. It may be unavoidable, but particularly with corporate IT systems that use OneDrive and other similar systems, the modified and created dates can reflect when a file was most recently opened or synced.

Comment: @SamR: The modified date changes when the file is opened but the created date remains the same. So using the max `ctime` variable from the output dataframe from `file.info` will give the latest file.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `file.info` function as suggested by @vincent-guillemot, we can use the below code to find latest file.

```r
my_folder <- "C:/Users/katti/My Drive/Dropbox/07_Learning"

files_in_folder <- list.files(my_folder, pattern = ".xlsx", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

xlsx_df <- file.info(files_in_folder)

xlsx_df$filename <- rownames(xlsx_df)

xlsx_df[xlsx_df$ctime == min(xlsx_df$ctime),"filename"]
#> [1] "C:/Users/katti/My Drive/Dropbox/07_Learning/Blank_CF - Copy.xlsx"
```

Not the `recursive=TRUE` argument in `list.files`. This allows you to also look into subfolders and search for `.xlsx` files. Set it to `FALSE` if you only want to search in current folder.